# Dynamic Dependency Injection Spring

Tags: spring, dynamic, dependency-injection

I have following code inside my class

```
public void startListeners() throws Exception {
        List<QueueConfiguration> queueConfigs = queueConfigResolver.getQueueConfigurations();
        for(QueueConfiguration queueConfig : queueConfigs){
            //TODO : work on this make it more testable
            ICustomListener readerListener = new MyCustomListener(queueConfig);
            readerListeners.add(readerListener);
            readerListener.start();
        }

    }
```

I am using Spring for dependency injection(not in this case but overall). Now there two problems with this code.

1. I cannot put mock for each of the listeners created, while testing.
2. I dont want to use ApplicationContext.getBean() because it will have same affect. AFAIK spring cannot do this dynamically , but any other pointers?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more detailed what exactly you wanna test? The queueConfiguration or the listener? Why you do not wanna use the applicationcontext.getbean exactly? And what is Spring not able to do dynamically. What means dynamically in this case?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you want to create a new bean instead of 
   ICustomListener readerListener = new MyCustomListener(queueConfig);
If that is the case, creating a factory for mycustomlistener and using

```
public abstract TestClient createTestClient();
```

to create your beans, and defining

```
<bean id="testClient" class="com.myproject.testbeans.TestClient" scope="prototype">     
</bean>
<bean id="testClientFactory" class="com.myproject.testbeans.TestClientFactory">
    <lookup-method name="createTestClient" bean="testClient" />
</bean>
```

in your context will solve your problem. This way, every time the createTestClient method of the factory is called, a new bean is created and given to your code. However, you have to give the config object via a setter instead of the constructor.